Splitting monitor xrandr into multiple split-screen virtual monitors not working
I am running Redhat 8 that I am using with a 43"x24" LG monitor. I would like to divide the monitor into 2 or 4 sections that I can use as individual virtual monitors using xrandr. I found a few guides online (like this and this) that describe how to do it, but when I attempt it, nothing happens.
Here is what I did:
$ xrandr --listactivemonitors
     0: +*DP-1 3840/600x2160/240+0+0 DP-1

$ xrandr --setmonitor LEFT 1920/300x2160/340+0+0 DP-1
  output list DP-1
  add monitor DP-1
  output name DP-1
$ xrandr --setmonitor RIGHT 1920/300x2160/340+1920+0 none
$ xrandr --fb 3841x2160
$ xrandr --fb 3840x2160

$ xrandr --listactivemonitors
  0: LEFT 1920/300x2160/340+0+0 DP-1
  1: RIGHT 1920/300x2160/340+1920+0

As you can see, xrandr detects both "monitors" after I execute the --setmonitor command, but my screen still only has one division and nothing has changed. The guides said that if nothing happens, you might need to refresh the monitors using the --fb command, hence changing the resolution by one pixel and back again after setting the monitors. Still, nothing happens. Does anyone know why this wouldn't be working and potentially how to fix it?
